# Maintaining Password History in SharePoint 2013 (FBA)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 (on premise) application where I have implemented Forms Based Authentication (FBA) wherein usernames and passwords are saved (in encrypted format) in SQL membership database. Now when any user changes his/her password (via custom login page), the old password gets overrides and hence the last five passowrds are not saved in the database.

I just want to know if SQL membership database provides any functionality to store/save the previous passwords.

Quick help would be highly appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's nothing built into the SQL Membership provider, so you will have to customize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the user password cannot be retrieved in the **Membership database**.

In the **machine.config**

```
<add name="FBAMembershipProvider"
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
 connectionStringName="FBADB"
 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
 enablePasswordReset="true"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
 applicationName="/"
 requiresUniqueEmail="true"
 passwordFormat="Hashed"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
 minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
 passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

**Note:passwordFormat=Clear/Hashed/Encrypted**

- **Clear** stores the password in the database as plain text, so anybody with access to the database can read the user’s password.
- **Encrypted** encrypts the user’s password, so although the password isn’t human readable in the database, it can still be decrypted and
  the user’s actual password retrieved.
- **Hashed** stores a one way hash of the password.  When a user authenticates, the password they enter is hashed as well and matched against the stored hashed value. **Using this method, the user’s password can never be retrieved** (even if your database is stolen),only reset.

Generally, recommend using “**Hashed**” as it is the most secure way of storing the user’s password.